# How to Properly Check for JSON Updates - Java

Tags: java, json, loops, http

I'm trying to make a program to check for announcements via a web API - This connects to a remote server and reads the JSON on the page - I cannot test my code as the server is not live yet. Would this work & be the correct way to go about this?

```
public class AnnouncementChecker implements Runnable{

private final String announcementsURL = "REDACTED";
private String lastAnnouncement = "";

@Override
public void run(){
    try {
        URL url = new URL(announcementsURL);
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        http.setRequestMethod("conditional GET");
        http.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        http.setUseCaches(true);
        http.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        if (lastAnnouncement != ""){
            http.setRequestProperty("If-Modified-Since", lastAnnouncement);
        }
        http.setConnectTimeout(10);
        http.connect();
        int status = http.getResponseCode();
        if (status == 304 || (status == 200 && lastAnnouncement == "")){
            lastAnnouncement = http.getHeaderField("Last-Modified");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            br.close();
            String json = sb.toString();
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonResponse = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
            //String announcement = (String) jsonResponse.get("message");
            //TODO What to do with announcement...
        }
        http.getInputStream().close();
        http.disconnect();

    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You probably ought to include more context as to what "this" is.

Comment: @BenKnoble Don't really know how to explain it anymore - It seemed self explanatory to others :/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up a test of some kind, despite the server not being available. This would give you the answer to your question and the test would be there forever going forward to protect you when you make changes to the code and the business requirements change.

To help you with that I would recommend splitting up the code that returns the response and the code that does the parsing. That way you can test the parsing independent of the part that makes the HTTP connection.

If you have no idea how to do that then I'd be happy to post an example for you.

Comment: I plan on splitting up the code later on - The main question is, do you see any issues anywhere? I would also setup a test but this main server is planned to be up shortly anyway i'm just trying to get everything done before hand :P

Comment: http.setRequestMethod("conditional GET") should probably be http.setRequestMethod("GET"). Other than that I don't see anything that looks wrong but I don't have much confidence in that statement without writing a test. You might also consider using an HTTP client library or even a library that handles json parsing. Not sure if you are a Spring fan but the Spring RestTemplate works like a charm for situations like this.